# Issue in URL: Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

### **What is it about ?**

On Godaddy Shared Hosting, I have space on Linux Server. My Directory Structure is like below in the screenshot

[image]

**We can see from the above screenshot that the app is inside the Framework folder and Framework folder is in the root.**

### **What's the Problem ?**

In the First screenshot, we can find Users Directory inside Framework folder. That has file in the below given path

```
Framework/Users/Helper/Profile/user.png
```

I am not able to make the url that can point to above mentioned file.

### **What I tried so far ?**

```
<img src="{{URL::asset('/Users/Helper/Profile/User.png')}}"}}
```

**Am I missing something ?**

Comment: That's because you're allowed to display things only from public_html folder. Please keep all public files like (images, css, javascript, videos, fonts) only in public_html directory or in it's subdirectories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would suggest is that you move all the folders inside the Framework folder and move them into the root folder. Basically, just get rid of the Framework folder. This would allow you to use the helper methods.

Then move the Users folder into the public_html folder, and you should be good to go.

Your directory structure should look like this after you remove the Framework folder and move it's content in the root folder.

```
- app
- bootstrap
- config
- database
- resources
- storage
- tests
- vendor
- logs
- mail
- public_html
    - Users
```

Comment: Try moving all the content inside the Framework folder outside.

Comment: you can use the Helper public_path('Users/Helper')

Comment: Update your directory structure, like the example I provided.

Comment: try using base_path('public_html/Users/Helper')